# How can I get children DIV class name by clicking that div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how can it be achieved that when a div is clicked and value is changed, that div class name to be saved to another variable?

Here is the code.

```
<div id="tradicionalen" contenteditable="true">
<div class="tradicionalen-0">0.1</div>
<div class="tradicionalen-1">0.5</div>
<div class="tradicionalen-2">1.1</div>
<div class="tradicionalen-3">1.7</div>
<div class="tradicionalen-4">2.8</div>
<div class="tradicionalen-5">4.4</div>
<div class="tradicionalen-6">5</div>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
$("#tradicionalen").children().click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

and

```
$("#tradicionalen").find("div").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

and

```
$("#tradicionalen div").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

and still no luck.

I'm using this so I can save the table for later use.

Thanks!

Comment: If your JavaScript is placed 'Above' where the 'HTML' for the `<div>` elements is written, then the `<div>` elements do not exist yet when your `.click` is assigned. You must make sure the JavaScript runs 'After' the `<div>` elements are created.  A way to do this is to place your JavaScript 'Below' where the HTML for the `<div>` elements is written.

Comment: @FactoryAidan that seems the problem. I'm creating a div table using function and even thou I see the table in my browser, I dont see it in the Page Source.

Answer (score 1):

What you've pasted above should work:

```
var savedVariable;

$("#tradicionalen div").click(function(){
  savedVariable = $(this).attr("class");
  console.log('Updated: ' + savedVariable);
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/biwako/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

You can also use delegated events:

```
 $("#tradicionalen").on("click", "div", function () {
      console.log($(this).attr("class"));
 });
```

Doing it like this attaches *one* event handler to the `#tradicionalen` element. When any `div` inside `#tradicionalen` is clicked, the event bubbles upwards until it is caught by the handler, which passes it on to the appropriate callback function.